# Footer doesn't go at bottom

Tags: css, materialize

I have a web page built with materialize css library.

This is the screenshot:
[image]
As you can see, the footer doesn't go at bottom, but remains attached to the last item (step 5).

I didn't modify any file from materialize library.

How can fix?

Comment: Give the footer a `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` CSS

Answer (score 0):

Use this for the footer:

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Think it should be absolute instead of fixed?

Comment: Sure, good catch. Thanks.

Comment: If the page is scrollable, the footer remains at its position, not working.

Comment: The problem wasn’t that it wasn’t at the bottom?

Comment: Yes, only if the contents don't arrive at bottom page.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? If yes, try to search "sticky footer".
Here is a good a link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sticky-footer/