# footer doesn't appear on bottom of page when using 100vh

Tags: html, css, alignment, footer

**Description:**

I have want to structure my website into several pages using following css:

```css
.page {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

I add several pages to the website and on the last one I want a footer to appear on the bottom of the page, e.g.

```css
.page {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: cyan;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">Page 1</div>
<div class="page">Page 2</div>
<div class="page">
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried to set position: absolute (of footer) like in this answer: [css - footer doesn't go at bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63476647/footer-doesnt-go-at-bottom)
- I also tried to put a wrapper around the footer with height: 100%;
- I've also used min-height: 100vh instead of height with no effect

**The question:**

How can I get the footer to the bottom of the page?

PS: I don't know if it's relevant but I'm using Firefox v. 85.0.2 (64-bit)

**Edit:**

I want the footer to be inside the page, I use these pages to structure my website and the footer should appear on the bottom of the very last page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will solve your problem:

```css
.page {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: cyan;
}

.spacer {
    flex: 1;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">Page 1</div>
<div class="page">Page 2</div>
<div class="page">Page 3
<div class="spacer"></div>
<footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: That would work but I actually want the footer to be inside of the page.

Comment: I want to be able to position the elements inside the page, to generalize my question

Comment: Answer revised.